# Создание кнопки в контекстном меню проводника Windows

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Создаю в реестре пункт меню и запуск программы по нажатию на него следующим образом -

```
        RegistryKey key;

        key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"*\Unlocker");
        key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"*\Unlocker\command");
        key.SetValue("", Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Как я могу получить имя файла или папки, с меню которых была открыта программа?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Аргументами при старте конечно, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Environment_GetCommandLineArgs `string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(); `

Comment: @NewView при запуске возвращается только 1 аргумент - это путь до той программы, чьи аргументы я смотрю. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Приложение какое? Консоль? ВинФорм? ВПФ?

Comment: @ NewView ВинФорм, в тегах же указано

Comment: Посмотрите пока вот это https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentCommandLineParser/, а вообще странно, что значит 1 аргумент? Возможно поправить Майн метод: `static void Main(string[] args)`

Comment: @NewView спасибо, сейчас попробую.
UPD: не пашет(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88552/discussion-between-stepan-and-newview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если команда состоит только из пути к программе, и не содержит параметров, то никак. Чтобы была возможность получить имя файла, команда должна выглядеть как-то так:

```
"\""+Application.ExecutablePath+"\" \"%1\""
```

Проводник подставит вместо %1 имя открываемого файла, и он будет передан в программу параметром командной строки. Тогда вы сможете его считать через аргумент функции Main.